# Looking to see if an item in a list is in a string Python 2.7

Tags: python

I'm trying to see if an item in a list (domain) is in a string (email), and if it is, then print that the email has a domain in it. Python tells me "'in ' requires string as left operand, not list" and won't let me compare them together. Does anyone know how to compare a single item in a list with a string? Thanks in advance!

```
at = '@'
period = '.'
domain = ['.com', '.edu', '.gov', '.org', '.net', '.aaa', '.aarp', 'abb', '.abbott', '.abbvie', '.abogado', '.abudhabi', '.ac', '.academy', '.accenture', '.accountant', '.accountants', '.aco', '.active', '.actor', '.ad', '.adac', '.ads', '.adult', ]
email = raw_input("What is your email? > ")


if period not in email:
    print("You failed")
else:
    print("You have an @ symbol!")


if period not in email:
    print("You do not have a period in your email")
else:
    print("You have a period in your email")


if domain not in email:
    print("You do not have a domain in your e-mail. Oops!")
else:
    print("You have a domain in your email!")
```

Comment: You will have to loop over `domain` and check if `email` ends with each domain. Or you can extract the domain from the email and check if it is `in domain`.

Comment: How does `.` not being in the email mean you do have `@`? Also why are you doing `if period not in email:` twice? I think you might need to read a tutorial or two  http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think he mistyped `period` instead of `at`. There's a `period` checker below it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do the contains-check for each item in the list separately. There is some syntactic Python sugar for this though:

```
if any(x in email for x in domain):
    # good: email contains one of the domains
```

or more to the point (of validating emails):

```
if all(not email.endswith(x) for x in domain):
    # rain hellfire on user
```

Comment: What about `email.endswith(x)`?

Comment: That's what you and I know about emails, isn't it. It is not what the OP's code indicates that he wants to do ;)

Comment: @schwobaseggl, the OP also thinks that not have a period means you automatically have an `@`

Comment: Well, we could lend him an hand.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It could be a simple typo by the OP :)

Comment: @Arpan, well python does not know about typo's ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong in your own code but the simplest and fastest way is to slice the .whatever and do a lookup in a set of domains:

```
domains = {'.com', '.edu', '.gov', '.org', '.net', '.aaa', '.aarp', 'abb', '.abbott', '.abbvie', '.abogado', '.abudhabi', '.ac', '.academy', '.accenture', '.accountant', '.accountants', '.aco', '.active', '.actor', '.ad', '.adac', '.ads', '.adult',}


email = raw_input("What is your email? > ")

dom = email[email.rfind("."):]
```

You should use a while True loop if you want to keep asking:

```
at = '@'
period = '.'
domains = {'.com', '.edu', '.gov', '.org', '.net', '.aaa', '.aarp', 'abb', '.abbott', '.abbvie', '.abogado', '.abudhabi', '.ac', '.academy', '.accenture', '.accountant', '.accountants', '.aco', '.active', '.actor', '.ad', '.adac', '.ads', '.adult',}
while True:
    email = input("What is your email? > ")
    if at not in email:
        print("You failed, no @ in your email addrress.")
        continue
    print("You have an @ symbol!")

    if period not in email:
        print("You do not have a period in your email")
        continue
    print("You have a period in your email")

    if email[email.rfind("."):]  in email:
          print("You have a domain in your email!")
          break          
    print("You do not have a domain in your e-mail. Oops!")

print(email)
```

If you were to use endswith, it is simply a matter of passing a tuple of domains:

```
domains = ('.com', '.edu', '.gov', '.org', '.net', '.aaa', '.aarp', 'abb', '.abbott', '.abbvie', '.abogado', '.abudhabi', '.ac', '.academy', '.accenture', '.accountant', '.accountants', '.aco', '.active', '.actor', '.ad', '.adac', '.ads', '.adult')
```

Then sinply:

```
if email.endswith(domains)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just wanted to see if the email addresses contains the domain or not then you could simply use the find function in python that would return the index where you would get the sub string.

Here is my way

```
domain = ['.com', '.edu', '.gov', '.org', '.net', '.aaa', '.aarp', 'abb', '.abbott', '.abbvie', '.abogado', '.abudhabi', '.ac', '.academy', '.accenture', '.accountant', '.accountants', '.aco', '.active', '.actor', '.ad', '.adac', '.ads', '.adult', ]


email = raw_input("What is your email? > ")

for dom in domain:

     if(email.find(dom) != -1):
             print email
```